# how to stop auto rebuild app by changing of scss files in angular 5?

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, sass, angular5

when I change scss file. my app is rebuilt and page is refreshed. How to disable it. let just --watch .ts files. I run single command: ng serve --open

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop auto reloading only in case of scss file changes.

either you can stop auto reloading by running this command

```
ng serve --live-reload false
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, with @angular/cli, you can't natively achieve this using the .angular-cli.json configuration. But impossible is nothing :

If you really want to disable scss watch, you can eject the webpack configuration and use the WatchIgnore plugin. Source: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2425